# imports failing when executing python script from php

Tags: python, php, laravel, import, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to execute a Python script via PHP. It works to the point of starting the script, but fails at the imports. Here is the PHP-code:

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd("/resources/python/script.py");
$result = shell_exec("/usr/bin/python3 $command 2>&1");
echo($result)
?>
```

And this is the error I get when executing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/resources/python/script.py", line 20, in from googleapiclient import sample_tools ImportError: No module named 'googleapiclient'
```

The imports are not working, although when executing normally it works. I tried changing file modes with *chmod*, but that didn't change anything. I also tried moving the PHP-file into the same folder as the Python-script but then I couldn't access it via a Laravel Controller.

These are the imports inside the Python script:

```
17 import sys
18 import time
19
20 from googleapiclient import sample_tools
21 from googleapiclient.http import build_http
```

The first two imports seem to be working.
It's all running inside Laravel on a Ubuntu Linux Server.

Comment: I looked at similar questions and tried solutions but the problems always were slightly different.

Comment: It's throwing an error from python script! You fix that first.

Comment: @RintoGeorge Read the question. It runs fine directly from Python.

Comment: @RintoGeorge Yes, I know it is. But when executing it normally this error does not appear. So it has to do with the execution via PHP.

Comment: Its a python error, and you need to upgrade `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client`

Comment: @sta the package is up to date, I checked it.

Comment: @yarvis While my knowledge in Python is VERY limited, I think this actually has less to do with PHP and probably more with your executing shell environment. PHP is executing your Python script not from `bash`, but from a standard `sh`. So if you have environment variables that Python 3 requires, those may not be set properly and could be messing with things.

Comment: I've ran scripts like this, but I made sure the path of the script is right. Instead of using relative path, use realpath for ex. /var/www/html/resources/python/bla/bla . I am not sure your path is relative or realpath, but that's a try.

Comment: @RintoGeorge thanks, I actually am using the real path, I changed it in the question for privacy reasons

Comment: @maiorano84 thanks for the tip, I will look into that.